# Codename One get Value from Component

Tags: drag-and-drop, containers, codenameone

I am working on an application that uses drag&drop operations with labels (a game in which the words have to be arranged in the correct order).

The labels are added dynamically to a container and I want to use a button action to retrieve the text of the labels.

But the button only prints the content of the last label. How can I get capture of the content of all of them?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
String word = "ma:to:to";
String delimiter = ":";
StringTokenizer wordTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(word, delimiter);

while (wordTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {             

        tokenLabel = new Label(wordTokenizer.nextToken());
        tokenLabel.setUIID("LabelWord");
        tokenLabel.setDraggable(true);
        container_1.add(tokenLabel);
}

buttonDialog.addActionListener((e) -> {   

        for (Component component : container_1) {                
            String s = component.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
        } 

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the exact use case for `putClientProperty` see [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/property-of-the-client.html).

You can just do:

```
myLabel.putClientProperty("metaData", myData);
```

Then later:

```
Object myData = myLabel.getClientProperty("metaData");
```